# Is it possible to make a Unique Identifier between several lists in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm making several lists in one SharePoint site for reporting purposes, and I need some way to create a unique Identifier across all of these items in all of the lists.

Comment: This is what GUIDs were invented for.